# Flutter find color between two colors depending on the value

Tags: flutter, dart

Maybe I could't word my query properly, let me explain what I mean.

I have a variable and depending on its value I want to show colors like:

```
var percent = 0; // show red color
var percent = 50; // show middle of red and green
var percent = 100; // show green color
```

Comment: `Color.lerp(Color(0xffff0000), Color(0xff00ff00), 0.5)` works as intended

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work @Eugene.

Comment: I tried and it works

Comment: Sorry I tried and it works actually, I forgot to put 0.5 there, I had percent set to `0`.

Answer (score 8):

```
Color color = Color.lerp(Colors.red, Colors.green, percent);
```

Does the trick!

Comment: just FYI, Color.red not pure RED :)

Comment: Yes it is `Colors.red[500]` @Eugene.

Comment: @Eugene is right. Red is `#FFFF0000`, `Colors.red[500]` is `#FFF44336`.

Comment: @janstol I meant `Colors.red` is `Colors.red[500]`.